# Merge and convert date and time in IST format to UTC format

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2

I am trying to convert date and time entered by customer from IST format to UTC format because I am storing all data in database in UTC format. But the problem I am facing is I am getting different timestamp in which the date is completely different and also the date time doesn't seems to UTC datetime. What I am trying to do is, I am merging first the date and time in IST format and then I am converting it to UTC format. and then separating date and time from them. My nodejs server is hosted in aws EC2 instance.

```
deliveryOrPickUpDate = req.body.deliveryOrPickUpDate;
deliveryOrPickUpTime = req.body.deliveryOrPickUpTime;
console.log(deliveryOrPickUpDate);
console.log(deliveryOrPickUpTime);

let deliveryOrPickUpTimehh = deliveryOrPickUpTime.substring(0,2);
let deliveryOrPickUpTimemm = deliveryOrPickUpTime.substring(3,5);
console.log("deliveryOrPickUpTimehh is :", deliveryOrPickUpTimehh);
console.log("deliveryOrPickUpTimemm is : ", deliveryOrPickUpTimemm);

ISTDateTime = deliveryOrPickUpDate + 'T' + deliveryOrPickUpTimehh + ':' + deliveryOrPickUpTimemm + ':' + '00.000'; //Constucting in T format but without Z to say its not UTC and just any other time
console.log("ISTDateTime selected is : ", ISTDateTime);

utcDate = new Date(ISTDateTime); //Converting IST to UTC here
console.log(utcDate);

utcDate.setDate(utcDate.getHours() - 5);
utcDate.setDate(utcDate.getMinutes() - 30);

dateISTString = utcDate.toUTCString(); // date in IST format
console.log("India time now is ", dateISTString);

dateUtc =  utcDate.toISOString().slice(0,10);
console.log("Date in UTC is : ", dateUtc);

timeUtc =  utcDate.toISOString().slice(11,19);
console.log("Time in UTC is : ", timeUtc);
```

Example Console output is below

```
2023-03-30
22:34:00
deliveryOrPickUpTimehh is : 22
deliveryOrPickUpTimemm is :  34
ISTDateTime selected is :  2023-03-30T22:34:00.000
2023-03-30T17:04:00.000Z
India time now is  Sat, 04 Mar 2023 17:04:00 GMT
Date in UTC is :  2023-03-04
Time in UTC is :  17:04:00
```

These are the two input date and time:

```
2023-03-30
22:34:00
```

Comment: not including the `Z` just ends up using the timezone of the system it's run on. To maintain control of the timezone you need to specify either `Z` or a specific offset, so if you know it is IST then apply the offset `'2023-03-30T22:34:00.000+05:30'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/).

Luxon is small, clean and modern. It also doesn't drag along the entire `tzdb` — it uses native internationalization support in Node and browser.

```
const { DateTime } = require('luxon');

const date = "2023-03-30";
const time = "22:34:00";

const IST = 'Asia/Kolkata' ;
const dtLocal = DateTime.fromISO(`${date}T${time}`, { zone: IST } );
const dtUtc   = dtLocal.toUTC();

console.log(`LOCAL: ${dtLocal.toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')} IST`);
console.log(`UTC:   ${dtUtc.toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')} UTC`);
```

Which yields:

```
LOCAL: 2023-03-30 22:34:00 IST
UTC:   2023-03-30 17:04:00 UTC
```

**Edited to note:** to get the date and time individually, as strings, one can [**read the documentation**](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetime) and note that an instance of a Luxon `DateTime` comes with these methods:

- [`.toISODate()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoisodate) method
- [`.toISOTime()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoisotime)

Which will do exactly what you want.

One should note that these two methods are largely convenience wrappers around `.toFormat()`.

- `.toISODate()` is pretty much just `.toFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')`, and
- `.toISOTime() is pretty much just` .toFormat('HH:mm:ss')`

with some logic to interpret the options and tweak the format string appropriately.

Comment: This seems to do the magic, but how do I get the Date and Time fetched from UTC date. Like I wanted to fetch 2023-03-30 and 17:04:00 ?